# Sequelize are all of these correct ways to use OR operator?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've seen 3 ways people use OR operator...

```
where: { $or : [ {attr:val}, {attr:val}] }
```

--

```
where: { $or : { attr:val, attr:val} }
```

--

```
where: { attr: { $or: [val, val] } }
```

are all of these valid? and any gotchas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong and don't intend for up-vote.

Better use examples from [official documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#where).

and enable [logging mode (see logging param)](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/usage.html#options) to see what happens on particular query

but I'll try to give some idea.

I prefer this one - since it's more readable :

```
where: { $or : [ {attr:val1, some: val3}, {attr:val2} ] }
```

is

```
... WHERE ((attr = val1 AND some = val3) OR (attr = val2))
```

This one I cannot tell which value is taken to comparing. Since it's not an array, so I may guess that it will use last definition and because there is no other fields to build query it will not use `OR`

```
where: { $or : { attr: val1, attr: val2} }
```

is

```
... WHERE attr = val2
```

extra:

```
where: { 
  user_id: 5, 
  $or : { attr: val1, attr: val2} 
}
```

is

```
... WHERE user_id = 5 OR attr = val2
```

third one a bit ambiguous, I would recommend to use `$in`

```
where: { attr: { $in: [val1, val2] } }
```

is

```
... WHERE attr IN (val1, val2)
```

Comment: what if it was like this instead `where: { $or : { attr1:val1, attr2:val2} }`

Comment: so they are all valid syntax, documentation doesn't list them, 1st one is shown, 2nd one is implied, no where it mentions 3rd one

Comment: @MuhammadUmer 3rd I don't know, it's just a guess, 3rd seems to be better with: `attr: {$in: [val1, val2]}`